# sed replace only lines with matching groups

Tags: sed

Currently, I have this command:

```
sed 's/\([^C]*\)/\1AB/'
```

It inserts "AB" before the first instance of "C" on a line. But it is also adding "AB" at the end of every line without a "C".

How can I have it only edit when it finds "C"?

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with simply replacing the `C`?

```
sed 's/C/ABC/'
```

This will only replace the first instance (if you wanted to replace them all, you would add `g` at the end).

Answer (score 4):

You need an address filter:

```
sed '/C/s/\([^C]*\)/\1AB/'
```